# Is it safe to call self in std::async

Tags: c++11

I would like to check Mysql connections are alive.
(using Mysql-connector-c++)

so.. I call "check function" every 5 minutes

like this

```
void checkConnection()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::minutes(5));
    // -- check connection
    std::async(std::launch::async, checkConnection); // Here
}
```

Is it safe..??

Comment: What makes you think its not safe? generally speaking using std::async let you rid of from thread management and gives you a task based programming.

Comment: I worry infinite thread creation. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case you specified, it is safe, because `std::launch::async`—when by itself—specifies that you want this to be done on a separate thread. The danger, otherwise, would have been stack overflow due to recursive calls.

However, note that the behavior here would be:

1. Sleep 5 mins on thread T1
2. Check connection on T1
3. Start new thread T2
4. End thread T1
5. Sleep 5 mins on thread T2
6. ...

So you'd always be using one thread, except you'll pay for creation and destruction each time. It's better to use just one thread, e.g.

```
void checkConnection(std::atomic<bool>& stopFlag)
{
    using namespace std::chrono; // for 5min shorthand, if C++14

    while (!stopFlag) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(5min);
        // -- check connection
    }
}
```

Or better yet, use a thread pool for which you can specify delays. But that's not provided by the standard library as of yet.